# React Typescript and Webpack bundle @mui/material mimetype issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I am introducing **Webpack** into my React project (not CRA) and am experiencing a few issues.

It seems that I am facing an error with `@mui/material` being using within one of my sub dependencies?

When I am running the `webpack` command to bundle the project, it is erroring out with the all too familiar:

```
BREAKING CHANGE: The request '@mui/material/styles' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
```

I have done the rounds online and tried to delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and re-install the modules, however this didn't do anything.

Looking further at the error log, I can see that it is complaining about `@mui/material/styles` being used within a component library dependency I have included... Something I haven't encountered in other repos that use this same dependency.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/company_name/COMPONENT_LIB/dist/some-component/index.js 2:0-48
```

The component and line in question is as such:

```
import { useTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
```

The error log seems to suggest that there should be another `node_modules` in the dependency for it to reference against, yet there are no other errors where this lib dependency uses @mui/material's other bits and pieces?

Looking at the component library within `node_modules` in my project, you can see that `node_modules` is not included, but a `package.json` is which includes `@mui/material` as a dependency...

Am I missing something here?
Should I be including the `node_modules` within the build on the component lib?

**Full error log**

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/company_name/COMPONENT_LIB/dist/some-component/index.js 2:0-48
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mui/material/styles' in '/Users/username/MY_PROJECT/node_modules/company_name/COMPONENT_LIB/dist/some-component'
Did you mean 'index.js'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request '@mui/material/styles' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.
resolve '@mui/material/styles' in '/Users/username/MY_PROJECT/node_modules/company_name/COMPONENT_LIB/dist/some-component'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /Users/username/MY_PROJECT/node_modules/company_name/COMPONENT_LIB/package.json (relative path: ./dist/some-component)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      /Users/username/MY_PROJECT/node_modules/company_name/COMPONENT_LIB/dist/some-component/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/username/MY_PROJECT/node_modules/company_name/COMPONENT_LIB/dist/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/username/MY_PROJECT/node_modules/company_name/COMPONENT_LIB/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/username/MY_PROJECT/node_modules/company_name/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/username/MY_PROJECT/node_modules/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in /Users/username/MY_PROJECT/node_modules
        existing directory /Users/username/MY_PROJECT/node_modules/@mui/material
          using description file: /Users/username/MY_PROJECT/node_modules/@mui/material/package.json (relative path: .)
            using description file: /Users/username/MY_PROJECT/node_modules/@mui/material/package.json (relative path: ./styles)
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/username/MY_PROJECT/node_modules/@mui/material/styles is not a file
      /Users/username/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/username/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
 @ ./node_modules/company_name/COMPONENT_LIB/dist/index.js 32:0-43 303:0-650:2
 @ ./src/surface/index.tsx
 @ ./src/index.ts 2:0-26 2:0-26
```

**MY_PROJECT/tsconfig.json**

```
...
"compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "target": "esnext",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    ...
  }
...
```

**MY_PROJECT/webpack.config.js**

```
{
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
    }
}
```

**MY_PROJECT/package.json**

```
{
    "type": "module",
    "main": "dist/index.js",
    "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
    "files": [
        "dist"
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack",
        "prepare": "npm run build",
        ...
    },
    "dependencies": {
        ...
        "@babel/cli": "^7.22.10",
        "@babel/core": "^7.22.11",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.10",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.21.4",
        ...
        "@types/react": "^18.0.37",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
        ...
        "babel-loader": "^8.3.0",
        "eslint": "^8.47.0",
        ...
        "react-docgen-typescript-loader": "^3.7.2",
        "storybook": "^7.0.7",
        "ts-loader": "^9.4.4",
        "typescript": "^5.2.2",
        ...
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "tss-react": "^4.8.2"
        ...
        "webpack": "^5.88.2",
        "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: what's your package.json file

Comment: Maybe you are using webpack 5 version

Comment: @xgqfrms yes. Given I have only just decided to add webpack to my project, I've installed the latest version: `5.88.2` it seems. I have also included the relevant versions of React and webpack/babel things in my Q for you to see.

Comment: that's not enough, I want to see the whole package.json file

Comment: npm scripts and module type

Comment: You'd better create a minimal repro project using an online IDE such as `codesandbox`.

Comment: @xgqfrms updated. That's pretty much it. You asked about webpack v5 specifically... I know there are some issues with it and TS as mentioned in various places online... Do you think this is something similar here?